# Can I power an MCU using a 3.3V AC/DC module converter?

Tags: microcontroller, ac-dc, 3.3v

I'm designing a board that will connect to 230V AC. I found some ready to use AC/DC modules that can output 3.3V DC [Here's the list from Mouser](https://gr.mouser.com/c/power/power-supplies/ac-dc-power-modules/?sort=pricing).

Can I power an MCU directly from this output?. I'm guessing no without extra low pass filtering.
What I'd usually do I'd choose one with 5V output and add an extra LDO to drop the voltage down to 3.3V But I wonder if I can do it without any LDO if the main PSU provides 3.3V output.

Board requirements:
3.3V DC roughly 400mA
Voltage input 100V AC to 230V AC
Voltage ripple on 3.3V should not exceed 50mVp

Also, what kind of filtering should I add on AC side?
Any piece of advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I power an MCU directly from this output?

That would seem to be the point of a supply, wouldn't it?

We can't tell you how much current your application needs, so make sure that the supply is able to offer at least that much current.

> I'm guessing no without extra low pass filtering.

Any MCU will need decoupling caps. Together with the source impedance of the supply and the transmission impedance of the conductors connecting the MCU supply pins to that, this will form a low-pass filter.

So, no. Having no low-pass filter is physically impossible, but requires only the capacitors that you'll find specified in the MCU datasheet, assuming the power supply you select doesn't have excessive voltage ripple (which we can't know before you point us at the datasheet of the specific module, and we can't know the acceptable voltage ripple for your MCU and your application, but it seems unlikely that voltage ripple becomes a problem in a purely digital system, if you select one with sufficient current output).

This all boils down to: As anything in engineering, you need requirements from your specific use case and devices, and then you can check the specifications of the device you want to buy to fulfill these requirements.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have added some requirements

Comment: great, now you have the requirements. You need to go and check the supply device datasheets whether they fulfill it.